# How to configure Spring Boot logback RollingFileAppender and have actuator logfile?

Tags: spring-boot, logback, spring-boot-actuator

As I understand, /logfile actuator available only if `logging.file=` is in the application.properties file.

But for my logging I need RollingFileAppender file appender with SizeAndTimeBasedRollingPolicy.

Is it possible to configure RollingFileAppender in the application.properties?

If I configure RollingFileAppender in the logging-spring.xml there is an error:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - 'File' option has the same value "log/scratch6.log" as that given for appender [FILE] defined earlier.`

Is it possible to have logfile via RollingFileAppender and have a /logfile actuator?

Answer (score 5):

I faced the same issue.  Here is what i found

logging.file - actually creates a file. when you declare ${LOG_FILE} in your logback-spring.xml, it detects a collision. appender and file name with the same value.

I ended up doing this (appending with .log so that it differentiates the appender with the file)

application.properties:
 logging.file=/opt/fff/logs/file_debug

logback-spring.xml:

```
     <file>${LOG_FILE}.log</file>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <Pattern>
            %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
        </Pattern>
    </encoder>
```

..

However it also creates another file /opt/fff/logs/file_debug in addition to /opt/fff/logs/file_debug.log

Answer (score 0):

**Logback** is responsible for creating the log files, and you only want **spring actuator** to be able to read from the log file.

So keep your *logging-spring.xml* (or *logback.xml*) as is, and change the following property in **application.properties**,  from:

```
logging.file=/var/log/tomcat/scratch6.log
```

To:

```
endpoints.logfile.external-file=/var/log/tomcat/scratch6.log

# or for newer versions for springboot:

management.endpoint.logfile.external-file=/var/log/tomcat/scratch6.log
```